# How to update multiple bindable properties in specific order? (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, binding, flex4

I have a situation where I need to update a DropDownList's dataProvider and selectedItem 
in a specific order. See the following code ...

```
<s:DropDownList id="dropDownList"
                dataProvider="{someDataProvider}"
                selectedItem="{someSelectedItem}" />
```

In my case, some user interaction produces new values for the bindable variables "someDataProvider", and "someSelectedItem". However, when flex renders the DropDownList, the control's selected value is empty.

The reason for this is that the DropDownList's "selectedItem" property gets bound before the "dataProvider" property. The "dataProvider" needs to be bound first for "selectedItem" to be valid, this is because the new "selectedItem" points into the new "dataProvider".

***My question is, what is the best practice for updating bindable properties in a specific order?*** I've come up with a few ways (e.g. using a valueCommit handler), but I wanted to see what the community had to say.

Comment: My impulse is to say; don't use binding. Update the properties manually when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in order of forming data provider and selected item. If they form in the same Flash Player's frame after setting them into List they don't apply immediately. Flex uses invalidation to postpone real actions to the next frame.

To solve your problem please post more code. It will be good if you'll post code which forms data.

Is it possible that your selectedItem isn't really a member of your data provider (some kind of clone or so)? Objects of what type in your data provider?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem that has annoyed me for a long time.  It makes sense, but doesn't.  You'd want the selectedItem to be cleared if the data changes, but only if the data is actually different or doesn't hold your selected item.

Personally, I would just create a custom component extending the DropDownList and overriding the dataProvider, selectedItem and commitProperties to prevent clearing the selectedItem.